# Transition on multiple elements at the same time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Cheers! I'm having an issue debugging certain behavior that occurs mostly in the Chrome browser. Here is the simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/pd3xb2uo/

The objective is to transition multiple elements via JS code at the same time. In the example when you click on the button, items are moved to the left using `translate3d` added via JS. It works fine, but there are some caveats:

1. There is a small gap appearing between the items most of the time
2. Sometimes when you click faster on the button there is a large gap appearing between the items.

Here are the screenshots of both cases:

[image: small gap]

[image: large gap]

Any help or ideas on why it is happening would be highly appreciated:) It looks like there is a few milliseconds delay before the style attribute is updated on certain elements, but I have no idea why:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are transitioning 100 elements at the same time and because of half-pixel transitions.

If you know how wide and how many elements you have, then you can do it like so:

```js
 const container = document.querySelector('.container-inner');
 for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
   const div = document.createElement('div');
   div.classList.add('element');
   div.textContent = `Element ${i}`;
   container.appendChild(div);
 }
 let transition = 0;
 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
   transition -= 100;
   container.style.transform = `translateX(${transition}px)`;
 });
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container-inner{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.element {
  width: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform .3s;
  background-color: #A67583;
}
```

```html
<button>Move</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Now only one element gets transitioned and it is working smoothly.

Comment: Cheers! Thank you for the explanation and the example! Appreciated it!